# Prove: b passes the Fermat test for $m = p^2$ if and only if $b^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod {p^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

Question: Let $p$ be a prime and $b$ an integer with $\gcd(b,p) = 1$.
Prove: $b$ passes the Fermat test for $m = p^2$ if and only if $b^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod {p^2}$.

I know that if $b^{p-1}\not\equiv 1\pmod p$, then $p$ cannot be a prime.
However I don't know how to carry on proving this. Can someone please help me out with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I am using the same terminology as you but as I understand it you want to prove that if $p$ is prime and $\gcd(b,p)=1$ then
$$b^{p^2-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}\quad\hbox{if and only if}\quad
  b^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^2}\ .$$
For the "if" direction simply raise both sides to the power $p+1$.

Now assume that $b^{p^2-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}$.  Since $p$ is prime we have $b^p\equiv b\pmod p$, which can be written
$$b^p=kp+b$$
for some integer $k$.  Using the Binomial Theorem,
$$b^{p^2}=(b^p)^p=(kp+b)^p=\cdots+\Bigl({p\atop p-2}\Bigr)(kp)^2b^{p-2}+p(kp)b^{p-1}+b^p\ .$$
Now every term on the right hand side has a factor of $p^2$, except the last.  So
$$b^p\equiv b^{p^2}\pmod{p^2}\ .$$
Cancelling $b$, which is possible since $\gcd(b,p)=1$, and using our initial assumption,
$$b^{p-1}\equiv b^{p^2-1}\equiv 1\pmod{p^2}\ .$$

Comment: David, could you expand a little on the "if" part? When you say you just raise both sides to the power *p + 1*, do you mean for b^(p^2 − 1) ≡ 1 or the b^(p-1) ≡ 1 ? And how does this exactly prove the "if" part to the question? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @mudkip777344, you can take powers in congruence arithmetic.  So if $b^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod{p^2}$ then $(b^{p-1})^{p+1}\equiv1^{p+1}\pmod{p^2}$.  BTW sorry I didn't reply earlier but I didn't see your comment.  Tip: if you put "@David" in the comment then I will be notified of it (I think).

Comment: can you explain in further detail how i obtain b^p congruence b^(p^2) mod p^2 from the binomial expansion please?

Comment: @user210003 Expand $(kp+b)^p$ by the binomial theorem and write out the first three and the last three terms.  I am sure you will see that every term is an integer times $p^2$, except for the last.  If you have not yet learned the binomial theorem you can find it [here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/binomial-theorem.html).